# Python: storing settings in dictionary vs argparse.Namespace

Tags: python, shell, simulation, argparse

I'm doing some work on a scientific simulation, written in Python. I've inherited the code. The sim has several (~15–20) parameters which can vary from run to run – mostly numeric variables, plus a few Boolean flags. The main Python script takes these parameters as command line args and uses `argparse` to store them in an `argparse.Namespace` object.

In practice, rather than being typed out on the command line, the parameter values are stored in shell scripts for ease of reuse. These scripts serve no real purpose other than to run the Python script with the relevant command line args.

I'd like to store the parameter sets in human-readable (in particular, scientist-readable) and Python-parsable config files, and dispense with the shell script and `argparse` altogether. A consequence of this is that I would then be storing the parameters in a dictionary rather than a `Namespace`.

Are there any downsides to storing settings in a dictionary? Apart from the fact that `params.spam` is slightly more concise than `params['spam']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dict` is what `argparse` ultimately uses to host its `Namespace`, so, no problem using one directly.

Module `ConfigParser`, https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html , will parse a rather normal config file and store the settings in it for you.  It is, however, arranged by sections.  To extract a single section `'foo'`, given a populated config parser object `cp`,

```
adict = dict(cp.items('foo'))
```

will work.

For easier access syntax, you can use http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/ (an oldie but goldie:-)...

Comment: OMG, Alex Martelli came back! O.o

Comment: @felipsmartins, yep, been back a few weeks now -- my new job is about "1:many" tech support via public channels, and StackOverflow is definitely such a channel, so I can justify (some of) the time it takes me as part of my new job (though technically that's about google-something tags, not Python...:-)

Comment: Welcome back, ALex! Your answers are always enriching

Answer (score 1):

`Ipython` integrates config files and command line values.  There are default config files and user profile files.  And the `argparse` arguments are created from the config files.  So values are set and modified at multiple levels.  I'd have to dig into the code to be sure, but I think the values ultimately are stored in the kinds of structures that `config` produces rather than `argparse.Namespace`.

Internally, `argparse` accesses the Namespace with `getattr` and `setattr`. allowing maximum freedom in setting attribute names.  The Namespace class is about as simple as they come, with a few methods for comparison and display.

Namespace values could be added to a dictionary with a simple statement like:

```
d.update(vars(p.parse_args()))
```

I'd consider using `argparse.SUPPRESS` to keep default values out the Namespace, and thus keep them from changing values already present in the dictionary.